# How to assign value to a dynamic multidimensional dictionary in python with key from strings?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dynamic, key

I want to assign value to "original" dictionary with rule in "mapping".
How can I achieve that?

## Before Mapping

```
    original = {
       "id":0,
       "address":{
              "street_name":"",
              "street_number":0
       }
    }
```

## Mapping Recipe

```
    mapping = {
         "id":123,
         "address/street_name":"ABC",
         "address/street_number":124,
    }
```

## After Mapping

```
    original = {
       "id":123,
       "address":{
              "street_name":"ABC",
              "street_number":123
       }
    }
```

Comment: I did get value from this same scenario, but I don't know how to assign value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried?